# how to get multiple results using same query params django

Tags: python, django, url-routing

Is there a way to get two results from using the same query params in django. I find the second value overwrites the first

For example:

```
http://localhost:8000/?id=3&id=4
```

the result returns the value with `id=4` but i want result for `id=3` and `id=4`

Comment: What is the view logic that would handle the URL? That will determine how parameters should be passed. For example, in the view you could create a query with `.filter(id__in=[3,4])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the [`getlist()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) function of the QueryDict.

```
request.GET.getlist('myvar')
```