# Django query params to array

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the results from an array as explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogs?years=['2018', '2019']
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogs?years=[2018, 2019]
```

Turns out ['2018', '2019'] is not what i am getting as **years** , even though visually they look exactly the same.

I even tried using getlist as explained here [how to get multiple results using same query params django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914751/how-to-get-multiple-results-using-same-query-params-django) this does produce the desired results

```
def get_queryset(self):
        years = self.request.query_params.get('years')
        return self.queryset.filter(year__in=years)
```

Any clue on what am i doing wrong here?

I tried all options it does not work, while i type in the below statement it works perfectly fine

```
def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(year__in=['2018', '2019'])
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't believe this way will work. When you pass the value in querystring, I guess Django will recieve as a string.

**- EDIT -**

The above answer wont work is need to add more years, I got the solution `127.0.0.1:8000/blogs?years=2018&years=2019` and

```py
years = self.request.query_params.getlist('years', '')
```

converts this to list.

– @indavinci

Comment: The above answer wont work is need to add more years, I got the solution http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogs?years=2018&years=2019 and years = self.request.query_params.getlist('years', '') converts this to list.

Comment: Perfect! Will add your solution to the answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

If you have function based view this should work:

```
request.GET.getlist('years', '')
```

Comment: years = request.GET.getlist('years', [] )

Answer (score 6):

I think a better a better and cleaner way to solve this problem is to just pass the string as comma-separated values in query params and split them up in your Django View.

URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogs?years=2018,2019
```

Your View:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    years = self.request.query_params.get('years').split(',')
    return self.queryset.filter(year__in=years)
```

Comment: this is the way