# i added & instead of | between Q objects but it does not work

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-views

Sometimes i will search for type and color only
or name and year only, so Q should be able to compile request together

for example if i write "url/search/?q=action&q=Blue" it returns only the last query which in this case is "Blue"

**views.py**

```
def search_result(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    qs = Content.objects.distinct().search(query=query)

    query_string = request.GET.get('q')
    query_string = query_string.replace(';',',')
    
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    pagination = Paginator(qs, CONTENTS_PER_PAGE)
    
    try:
    qs = pagination.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
    qs = pagination.page(CONTENTS_PER_PAGE)
    except EmptyPage:
    qs = pagination.page(pagination.num_pages)
    
    context = {
    'SearchResults': qs,
    'query': query_string,
    }
    
    return render(request,
    'home/search_result.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class ContentQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
def search(self, query=None):
if query is None or query == "":
return self.none()
lookups = Q(genre__name__icontains=query) & Q(distributor__icontains=query) & Q(title__icontains=query) & Q(channels__name__icontains=query) & Q(year__icontains=query)
return self.filter(lookups)

class ContentManager(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self):
return ContentQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
def search(self, query=None):
return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)

class ChannelQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
def search(self, query=None):
if query is None or query == "":
return self.none()
lookups = Q(name__icontains=query)
return self.filter(lookups)

class ChannelManager(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self):
return ChannelQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
def search(self, query=None):
return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)
```

Comment: Please format that code properly. What would you expect to happen instead? What should `request.GET.get('q')` return in your opinion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django query params to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60013284/django-query-params-to-array)

Answer (score 0):

Where the querystring parameter is repeated as "q" is in `q=action&q=Blue`, you need to use the `getlist` method of the querydict:

```
query_strings = request.GET.getlist('q')
```

which should return `['action', 'Blue']`

See the [QueryDict doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects). The `get` method will return only one of the two strings. (Just checked ... the last)

Comment: so should i split query at comma either way?

i think i need to split my query at comma and then somehow tell that each object in that array is its own q

Comment: I don't completely follow. Django parses the querystring into a QueryDict object (request.GET) as per my answer. If `?q=a,b&q=c,d,e`getlist would return the list  `['a,b', 'c,d,e']` and your subsequent processing might involve splitting the list elements.

Comment: @AbubakarSiddique getlist returns ... a list of the query parameters named e.g. q . You then operate on that list, no need to split anything.

Comment: if i only ever search for same type of parameters, but sometimes i will search for type and color only or name and year only, so Q should be able to compile request together
how its possible

Comment: I was pointing out that you were throwing away `q=action` by using `get` instead of `getlist`. I don't follow the details of your use of Q objects; you certainly can combine them with `&` as well as `|`, I have often done so.

Comment: More generally, I don't often write all my own filtering code. Mostly I use the excellent django-filters package.

Comment: so this line is lookig for objects in array or am i missing something ?
`qs = Content.objects.distinct().search(query=query)''`

Comment: table with columns: name, color, type, year. I am doing a query with query Q to find my inputs and list them. Now I wonder how can i query multiple parameters and return objects that match all parameters. 
For example, if i search for "Blue,2003" it should return an only object that has these 2 values in a table

but if i type "Blue,2003" in search bar it returns nothing
if i search one query for example "Blue" i get results as i should